# How to keep the open windows in the right workspace while changing/rotating monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, monitor, workspaces, rotate-monitor

when I plug in/out an **external monitor** monitor, or I rotate the laptop monitor,  the **windows/applications open in the several workspaces often mess up**, such as in the following figure:

[image: windows messed up]

How can avoid it? I work with a laptop plugged to a bigger screen and a lot of windows open, and several times a day I unplug the external monitor to bring the laptop with me, resulting in this issue.

The same occours when I put my laptop (a "convertible" thinkpad X220T) in portrait mode.